# Concatenate two (or more) strings

Tags: acumatica

Is it possible to join two pieces of text together using BQL? I would like to use this in a PXFormula. A typical example would be to for example join name and surname together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you use the BQL Add function, the separator can be a string constant, ex:

```
private class string0101 : Constant<string>
{
    public string0101() : base("0101")
    {
    }
}

private class string01 : Constant<string>
{
    public string01() : base("01")
    {
    }
}

[PXFormula(typeof(Add<AP1099Year.finYear, string0101>))]    
[PXFormula(typeof(Add<AP1099Year.finYear, Add<string01, string01>>))]
```

The BQL and SQL Equivalents table list BQL Add function as equivalent to SQL Concat function:
[image]
Source: [BQL and SQL Equivalents](https://help.acumatica.com/(W(2))/?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=5e4ecd15-69fc-4f39-9076-0adb7a928129)

Answer (score 0):

Found it: SmartJoin. This provides functionality to concatenate strings and also include a separator. Just what I need.